# Azure Api Management restrict users from operational level

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

I am having an api with suppose 100 operations. I have created developer portal. my requirement is out of 100 operations, user A can only view the GET operations and User B can only view PUT and POST operations in developer portal once they logged in.

I am using username and password identity.

Kindly help on this. I have tried policies but not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this cannot be done just like that from the portal.

What you could do is setup the API in API Management twice. Once only with the GET operations and once with the POST operations. You would have two different API's to which you can grant access.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that on the managed portal because the narrower subscription level(scope) is the API/User level. You can self host the portal and achieve what you want but that will require considerable amount of work from your end.

[image]